# How to implement feature only in development environment for angular app?

Tags: angular

I have big multi step wizard form in my angular application and filling this form every time takes lots of time. I want to add button which will automatically fill my form on click, however, I don't want that button to exist in production neither function that will fill my form. I can hide/show button based on environment variables and *ngIf but the function will still be there in source code and I don't like that solution.

Comment: You could directly bind the data in the component.ts file and just remove initialising / populating the data before pushing to repo.

Comment: you can wrap the method body in if(!environment.production) {...} and during treeshake phase it should be removed, as the value will be resolved to `if(false)`